# Solr - range on the product of a facet function

Tags: solr, facet

I have a Solr core where each document represents a single copy of a product.  So there are many records with the same product ID.

I need to summarize sales by product, which I can do using a facet with an aggregation function, like this:

```
json.facet = {
products: {
        type: terms,
        field: product_id,
        limit: 1000,
        numBuckets: true,
        sort: "aggregated_sales desc",
        facet: {
            aggregated_sales: "sum(sum(sales_201606,sales_201605,sales_201604))"
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me a list of buckets like this:

```
"facets": {
"count": 53971,
"products": {
  "numBuckets": 21039,
  "buckets": [
    {
      "val": "0439023521",
      "count": 112,
      "aggregated_sales": 152
    },
    {
      "val": "0439023491",
      "count": 98,
      "aggregated_sales": 103
    },
```

...

This tells me that the 53,971 copies in the core represent 21,039 unique products, which are listed for me with their combined sales.

I have a reporting requirement to show a pie chart, where each segment represents a range of sales totals by product.  So one segment represents the count of products which sold 1-5 times, another segment represents the products that sold 6-10 times, and a third segment represents the products that sold more than 10 times.

How can I most efficiently get the ranges for this "aggregated_sales" facet function product?